# When a man is harassing a woman on the street saying something to her

Tags: phrase-request

I would be thankful if someone could let me know how an American English speaker would say my sentence. Suppose a very attractive girl is walking on the street and her beauty and figure attract all men's attention. A man gets in her way and politely OR impolitely says something to her in order to show her that he is attracted to her and wants to date her OR e.g. have a sexual relationship ith her or maybe wants to ask her for having a coffee together or something like that.
The only verbs I found were:

> - He [hit on](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hit-on-someone) her.
> - He pitched her up. (I have no reference! Once I heard a native used it in a similar scenario)

Comment: To *hit on* someone requires some social setting, like a party or a bar, or perhaps a coffee shop, where there is an implicit "contract" that people are fair game to be approached, at least until they spurn someone who has hit on them.  But to step in front of an unknown woman on the street to block her path goes well beyond 'hitting on' her. Some would consider it a form of harassment or even a kind of threatening behavior or assault.  And you are thinking of "pick someone up", which means to have casual sex with someone you have  only just met, in a bar, say, or at a party.

Comment: I don't mean to be giving you any advice beyond the meaning of the words.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few words a native speaker might use in this situation.

As a neutral phrase you'd probably say:

> He started chatting her up.
>
> He hit on her.

I disagree with the comment above that *hitting on* requires a social setting. I think it is perfectly valid to say that he started hitting on her as she walked along the street.

Chatting someone up implies talking to them with an aim to seduce or impress them. It is usually a light-hearted and playful phrase.

For an aggressive or unwelcome gesture, I would use:

> He harassed her as she walked down the street.
>
> He confronted her as she walked down the street.

The *pitched her up* idiom you have used I have not heard before.